# how to use multiview in radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, multiview

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
   </asp:View>
      <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server" 
       ...........contents......                                     
 </asp:View>

  </asp:MultiView
```

This is my multiview code, I have one radiolist in which I have 3 section one way,round trip and multicity, when I click on round trip it should switch me to the `view2` as I have mentioned. How can I do that?

Comment: You're kidding , right ... you didn't even paste the code in a readable way, you use l337 talk, and didn't make your question clear ...

Comment: @Noctis well, i just need an idea how to view the contents of view2 when i will click on one of my radiobuttonlist. what else code do you need tell me i will post.sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: If you don't take the time and consideration to make your question clear and easy to read, why should I (or anyone) waste my (or their) time reading and answering it? You posted some 200 lines of badly formatted code, which isn't aligned, and mostly irrelevant to the question. Maybe someone else will answer it ... but as it stands, I doubt it'll happen ...

Comment: @Noctis: well i am very new to this page, so  i dint had any idea about all that i mean allignment and all,and i thot giving whole code will help in solving this problem.once again sorry for that,and thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Cheers, not meant to sound rude, but they way you asked this, you won't get help.

Comment: @Noctis: i have edited to some extent.hope it will help in understanding my question.any suggestion regarding this would be of great help.

Comment: Please give the whole code in that case I can help you.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya : i just need an idea how to view the contents of view2 when i will click on one of my radiobuttonlist buttons.

Comment: You can use `ActiveViewIndex` property of multiview as follow: `ActiveViewIndex = 1` for selecting second view from multiView Control